# kde - Stuck with black background and blurry-transparent panels

Tags: kde

I installed '**Arc Dark**' theme, and activated. It changed all my 'panels' and the things into blurry-transparent that used to dark on Breeze Dark theme (panel, menu, notifications, etc).
I really didn't like it, so I just changed it.
But, it keeped the blurry-transparent, and I dont like it.
I tried deleting plasma/kde folders on `~`, `~/.local`, `~/.config`, `/usr` and more.
Reinstalled multiple times plasma/kde packages, but nothing.

Running kinda fresh install of Arch Linux.

Comment: well, im probably going to reinstall arch and plasma... PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

change the panel background.

go:
system configuration (aka configure desktop) > workspace appearance > desktop theme > details (tab) > panel background (select box/drop down) - select another themes background or a file; misc image or something you create (svg or png) > Apply.

Landis.